# Convert all values in a pandas column without getting a settingCopy Warning

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert all values in a pandas dataframe column from type int to str.
This has always worked with the code line:

```
kl['SAP'] = kl['SAP'].astype(str)
```

The script was running for years without any problem. For some reason I get the settingCopyWarning since two days.

I've looked for various solutions and tried them all but none off them seem to work.

Change the name off the column:

```
kl['SAP_FF'] = kl['SAP'].astype(str)
```

Use .loc as stated in the extra info when I get the error message:

```
kl['SAP'] = kl.loc[:, 'SAP'].astype(str)
```

Use .loc in combination with "astype(pd.StringDtype()":

```
kl.loc[:, 'SAP'] = kl.loc[:, 'SAP'].astype(pd.StringDtype())
```

Nothing works. I get the error message all the time. Anyone who knows a solution?

I checked all solutions on:

[How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Tt's a lot of text but I cannot find the simple solution to copy a column and convert values from type int to str.

Comment: How do you create `kl`? Is it part of bigger dataframe? Try to do `kl = kl.copy()`

Comment: It's not necessarily due to what you show here, but might be caused by something you did before (like slicing). Make sure to read the duplicate to see how to avoid this warning.